# Nuxt generate don't generate route html file

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a problem without solution, I finally finish my app but now I can't to generate full static site.
In my case, a little "multi arguments" blog, i didn't like how Nuxt generate the route, cause for my navigation system I need this layout:

Nuxt last version, node.js last version

```
index
blog
|-article one (child of blog)
|-article two (child of blog)
|-other pages (child of blog)
other blog
|-article one (child of other blog)
|-article two (child of other blog)
|-other pages (child of other blog)
```

The expected resoult should be:

```
mysite.io/

mysite.io/blog/articles-slug
    
mysite.io/blog-2/articles-slug
```

Maybe I'm wrong with the philosophie of nuxt? surelly

For do this I use ['@nuxtjs/router', { parsePages: 'true' }]

My route configuration is this:

```
 {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
          },
          {
            path: '/onstep',
            name: 'OnStep',
            component: OnstepMain,
            children: [
              { path: 'cosa-e-onstep', name: 'Cosa è OnStep', component: CosaOnStep },
              { path: 'configurazioni-possibili-di-onstep', name: 'Configurazioni Possibili', component: ConfOnStep },
              { path: 'moduli-necessari-per-la-scheda', name: 'Moduli Necessari', component: ModuliNecessari },
              { path: 'scelta-del-driver-per-motori-passo-passo', name: 'Scelta Del Driver Per Motori Passo Passo', component: SceltaDriver },
              { path: 'funzionamento-scelta-motori-passo-passo', name: 'Scelta e Funzinamento dei Motori Passo Passo', component: SceltaStepper },
              { path: 'calcolo-step-grado-montatura-eq-o-azm', name: 'Calcolo degli step/grado di una montatura EQ o AZM', component: CalcoloStep },
              { path: 'montare-la-scheda', name: 'Montare la Scheda', component: MontaScheda },
              { path: 'prepariamoci-a-scaricare-il-firmware', name: 'Preprariamo il PC', component: PreparaPC },
              { path: 'download-configurazione-firmware-onstep', name: 'Impostare il firmware di OnStep', component: FwOnstep },
              { path: 'configurazione-firmware-wifi', name: 'Impostare il firmware del WiFi', component: FwWiFi }, 
              { path: 'download-firmware-onstep', name: 'Download Firmware OnStep', component: DwOnstep },
            ]
          },
        ]
      })
```

When I do npm run generate --fail-on-error I get a lot of unfinded pages, cause the path where is looking is wrong:

```
 ERROR  Error generating route "/onstep/DownOnStep": This page could not be found                                                                                                                 19:05:38
```

**real route is /onstep/download-firmware-onstep**

Other strange thing is this, I get:

```
 ERROR  Error generating route "/onstep/CosaOnStep": This page could not be found
```

But at least, only for this child route, I get this:

```
√ Generated route "/onstep/cosa-e-onstep"
```

And the html page is ok...but he generate two folders:

onstep/cosa-e-onstep
and
onstep/CosaOnStep

Any suggestion?

If it can help this is my nuxt.config:

```
const path = require('path')

export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',
  ssr: 'true',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'stefanotesla',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'it'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css

  css: [
    '~assets/styles/tailwind.css', 
],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
   // '~router.js'
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/router', { parsePages: 'true' }],
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',

    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    'nuxt-purgecss',
  ],

  purgeCSS: {
    mode: 'postcss',
    enabled: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  },


  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://stefanotesla.it',
    gzip: true,
  },


  // Build Configuration: https://go.nunpm run devxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        tailwindcss: path.resolve(__dirname, './tailwind.config.js'),
        'postcss-nested': {}
      }
    },
    preset: {
      stage: 1 // see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#future-css-featuress
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What don't you like with the way Nuxt is doing this? Can't you have 2 directories (for your 2 blogs) and a `_slug.vue` for each? Can you explain your structure a bit better please?

Comment: Is my first project with js framework, so dynamic content is a little bit difficult for me to understand...
In my case I have blog1 folder, inside index.vue file and all article.vue file, I used child route cause in this way I can easily generate breadcrumbs and next/previous buttom, I can I get it with _slug.vue?? How can I define the article route??

Comment: Can you please edit your question for us to know what is the expected structure of your paths? Also, where do you fetch your articles? From Nuxt content, an API or do you simply hardcode it? Also, can you give more details on the breadcrumbs? Do you plan to actual have 3+ level of depth in your blog?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I edited the post, I'm olso trying the content module, and it works, but in default project _slug.vue file catch data only from content/article folder, how can I separate the two blog? My breadcrumbs is "wrong" is Vue route based, I get the matched URL and I create the breadcrumbs taking name and path, I can do the same splitting the actual URL and get the URL name...yes max depth should be host.com/blog1/article-slug

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved, if I route.js I have olso to declare in the nuxt.config.js the route path to prerender as here:

```
      generate: {
    routes: [ '/', 
              '/blog/',
              '/blog/article1',
            ]
  },
```